# How to configure auto-scaling with Bamboo Agents?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, autoscaling

We are able to launch new Bamboo agents and register them with the Bamboo server by using AWS auto scaling groups and using the user data, but scaling down is an issue.

A Bamboo agent is like a Jenkins slave. How can we automatically scale the bamboo agents cluster down e.g. from 12 to 8 nodes without killing current builds/jobs on the Bamboo agents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bamboo has "Elastic bamboo" which takes care of bringing up new agents and taking them now as required.

You can configure "elastic bamboo" from the bamboo server, in the admin section.